# Centered and responsive image in CSS

Tags: css, sass

Thank you for any help in advance!
I need this image to be centered and at the same time the height should decrease while resizing the browser window. The first thing is done already with flexbox. But unfortunately height stays the same. The width of the image is bigger then the viewport and that is the deliberate assumption.

Please check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/23nqgtz5/

html:

```
<div class="img-container">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x200" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/n48wb3ra/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `img` in another div and apply `flex: 1 1 auto;` property.

Give the img `max-width: 100%;` and control image width using padding of `.image`

HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Add below to CSS

```
.image {
    flex: 1 1 auto; 
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Be warned, flex isn't 100% compatible with all browsers

Comment: I wanted to get something like this https://jsfiddle.net/e6umygs1/1/, but your answer made the most of the job. Could you take a look at this and say is it correct approach?

Comment: @Murakami If you want the image to be centered, remove the margins on **.image** and make the img **width: 200%;**